# Trying to install pipenv install mysqlclient (There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, pipenv

I am trying to follow a django course my mosh and I am trying to install the `pipenv install mysqlclient` however I am unable to install and keep having this error..

```
(storefront) (base) tanweijie@localhost1-6 storefront % pipenv install mysqlclient
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing mysqlclient...
Resolving mysqlclient...
Adding mysqlclient to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (be1d61) out of date, updating to (f41128)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠹ Locking...
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 704, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 662, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 642, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1167, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 948, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/tanweijie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 690, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1
```

i tried clearing the cache like some other users suggested
`$ pipenv lock --pre --clear`
but when i run back `pipenv install mysqlclient`
It still does not work

Comment: Did you try to do what is proposed in the Warning?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by using this:

```
brew install mysql pkg-config

pip install mysqlclient
```

If they say brew command is not found do the following:

```
xcode-select --install

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After these two then run the first two commands again